# dictionary count how many times the key word occur in the articles

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I have two lists: `app`, and `topic_list`. In `app`, there are many apps, and in `topic_list` I store each word from the topic. Now I want to know which three apps have the highest occurrence for a given topic. My problem is that all the counters are 1 in `count_top_3` and they shouldn't be.

```
count_top_3 = {} #create a dictionary to store the times that the word occurs

for words in app:
    if words in topic_list:
        if words not in count_top_3:
            count_top_3[words] = 1
        else:
            count_top_3[words] += 1
print(count_top_3)
```

Edit:

app list looks like:

```
['Google Maps',
 'Facebook for Android',
 'Pandora?? internet radio',
 'Zedge Ringtones & Wallpapers',
 'Advanced Task Killer',
 'Twitter',
 'Tiny Flashlight + LED',
 'GO SMS Pro', ...]
```

and the topic_list looks like:

```
['Call Blocker X',
 'FNB Connect Phone',
 'LazyDroid Web Desktop',
 'Private Space Free(SMS & Call)',
 'Private Space Free',
 'Super Call Blocker',
 'Fast Society', ...]
```

here is my output of the dictionary:

```
{
    'Google Maps': 1, 
    'Facebook for Android': 1, 
    'Pandora?? internet radio': 1, 
    'Zedge Ringtones & Wallpapers': 1, 
    'Advanced Task Killer': 1, 
    'Twitter': 1, 
    'Tiny Flashlight + LED': 1, 
    'GO SMS Pro': 1, 
    'The Weather Channel': 1, 
    'Shazam': 1, 
    'Lookout Security & Antivirus': 1, 
    'YouTube': 1, 
    'Dictionary.com': 1, 
    'TuneIn Radio': 1, 
    'Movies': 1, 
    'ColorNote Notepad Notes': 1, 
    'Antivirus Free': 1, 
    'Bible': 1, 
    'TiKL': 1...}
```

**Actually, the value for the keys should not all be 1, I want to count how many times these apps occurs in the topic_list**

Comment: Please provide an example input and example output.

Comment: I edit it in below, thanks!

Comment: What is the output for those examples?

Comment: We would very much appreciate it if you'd add the input (what `app` and `topic_list` are), what you expect as output (what `count_top_3` should look like) and what you actually get (what `print (count_top_3)` shows). Otherwise we have no way to help you with this

Comment: I've edited it again ! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're only checking if `words` is in `topic_list` rather than the number of times it occurs (mapping a Boolean onto an integer instead of 
 mapping a collection of Booleans onto an integer) so you'll only ever get values of 1. The solution to your problem depends on the data in `app`:

**If the values in app are unique:**

In this case you can simple switch which data you use as your index. Since, drawing from your question, the values in `topic_list` are not unique, checking if they're in `app` will allow you to count them up without a large change to your logic.

```
for words in topic_list:
    if words in app:
        if words not in count_top_3:
            count_top_3[words] = 1
        else:
            count_top_3[words] += 1
print(count_top_3)
```

**If the values in app are not unique:**

In this case, if you try the first solution, you'll run into your current problem, just from the other data set. So, what you need to do is tally up the number of occurrences of `words` in `topic_list`:

```
for words in app:
    count = topic_list.count(words)
    if words not in count_top_3:
        count_top_3[words] = count
    else:
        count_top_3[words] += count
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your code works, an app placed in count_top_3 would only have a counter > 1 if the app was listed in app[] multiple times, since you are only checking if each app is **in** topic_list, and not **how many times** it is in topic_list. In your example input, there are no duplicates in app[].

If your goal is to count how many times each app appears in topic_list, you can loop over every app in app[], and for each app, then loop over every topic in topic_list[], and count how many times the topic matches that app, storing the result in count_top_3. You can also use the count() method for this.

Example:

```
for currentApp in app:
    count_top_3[currentApp] = topic_list.count(currentApp)
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried your method, but all my dictionary's count value become 10. For common sense, the counter should not be equal, because the data is the dataset contains ~180,000 applications from the Android app store...